# ClassNotFound exception while using the Maven Shade Plugin

Tags: java, maven, maven-2, maven-shade-plugin

I am trying to follow this link:
http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/examples.html

I am new to Maven. I feel a bit out of depth trying to follow the example.

I am able to get Quartz Scheduler to get working with Spring. I want to be able to run it from commandline using jar file.

Here are the list of classes and pom file I used.

[image: shade maven plugin]

EDIT:

I am able to get a shade jar file. I used mvn clean install

but when I try to run it from the command line, I get the following errors.

**`C:\Users\SpringExample\target>java -jar SpringExample-1.0-SNA
PSHOT-shaded.jar
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/sonatype/haven/Ex
odusCli
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.sonatype.haven.ExodusCli
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
Could not find the main class: org.sonatype.haven.ExodusCli. Program will exit.`**

EDIT2:

I used the following in the pom above using this link:

http://seanfreitag.wordpress.com/2011/07/25/create-an-executable-jar-with-dependencies-using-maven/

```
 <project>
  ...
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.4</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>shade</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <transformers>
                <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                  <manifestEntries>
                    <Main-Class>org.sonatype.haven.ExodusCli</Main-Class>
                    <Build-Number>123</Build-Number>
                  </manifestEntries>
                </transformer>
                <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.AppendingTransformer">
                  <resource>META-INF/spring.handlers</resource>
                </transformer>
                <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.AppendingTransformer">
                  <resource>META-INF/spring.schemas</resource>
                </transformer>
              </transformers>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
  ...
</project>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't used Shade, but I suspect that:

- the pom that you are using to invoke Shade is not shown
- the Maven example showing how to set a Main-Class assumes that the class org.sonatype.haven.HavenCli is somewhere in the jar being assembled
- you have no such class
- you should change the class name in your `<mainClass>org.sonatype.haven.HavenCli</mainClass>` to whatever you want to use as a main class

Answer (score 1):

UPDATE: You need to specify the Main-Class attribute in the Manifest.mf in your jar. See the example "Shade Plugin where a Main-Class is added to the MANIFEST.MF" for that.

--

Yes, you should embed the plugin code to your pom file like the following

```
<project>
       <!-- Other tags -->
        ---
    <build>
      <plugins>
        <plugin>
           ---
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </build>`
</project>
```

You have probably included the `<plugin>` as a direct child of `<project>` in the pom file. It doesn't work.

The usual way of building maven projects with `mvn install` (or `mvn package`) will create the shaded jar if the shade plugin configuration are specified. So, there will be two jars; the original jar and the uber jar.

exclude:
Generally, the uber jar will include all the classes in the `dependencies` jar list in the pom. the `excludes` specify a set of jar files that need NOT be in the shaded jar. If you have a closer look at the example, it excludes the junit:junit jar, which means that classes in the junit will not be in your uber jar.

Answer (score 0):

Add following snippet to your plugin. This should help.

```
 <artifactSet>
    <includes>
        <include>org.sonatype.haven.ExodusCli:*</include>
    </includes>
 </artifactSet>
```