# Maven Shade plugin: ClassNotFound exception with hadoop

Tags: maven, hadoop, maven-shade-plugin

When I try to use the Maven Shade plugin I get a hadoop version conflict.
I am trying to resolve it.

My `pom.xml` is:

```
<transformers>
    <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer" />
    <!-- The service transformer is needed to merge META-INF/services files -->
    <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ServicesResourceTransformer"/>
    <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ApacheNoticeResourceTransformer"/>
</transformers>

<relocations>
    <relocation>
        <pattern>org.apache.hadoop</pattern>
        <shadedPattern>my.shade.org.apache.hadoop</shadedPattern>
        </relocation>
</relocations>
```

The problem is that the `core-default.xml` reference does not change. Instead it causes a

> ClassNotFound exception.

Comment: I attempted to improve the readability of the question.

Comment: Maybe [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7363398/1305969) is of interest for you.

Comment: for example. i use rename org.apache.hadoop pre to my.shade.org.apache.hadoop  but core-site.xml file don't change hadoop.security.group.mapping property from  org.apache.hadoop.security.JniBasedUnixGroupsMappingWithFallback to 
my.shade.org.apache.hadoop..security.JniBasedUnixGroupsMappingWithFallback . i want to know how can i do. or the shade plugin can't do this. thinks.